# Как растянуть SideBar до конца?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, itemtouchhelper

Нужно сделать так, чтобы сайдбар растянулся до конца высоты контента

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.graficlogo {
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    background: #F6C010;
    margin: 0;
}

#sidebar {
  border-right: 5px solid #F6C010;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  background: #151718;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar h3 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar__icon {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #151718;
}

#sidebar__icon a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar__active {
  display: block !important;
}

.search {
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #F6C010;
  width: 30%;
  height: 15px;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  background: #1C1E1F;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #F6C010;
  transition: 0.25s;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
    background: #F6C010;
    height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.social p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.footer_social_img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tovari_items {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;

  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tovari_block {
  margin-top: -10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tovari_items:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.tovar_list h3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tovar_list p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6B6B6B;
}

#price h5 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F6C010;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#quantity_true h5 {
  margin-top: -17px;
  display: flex;
  color: #54C418;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#quantity_false h5 {
  margin-top: -17px;
  display: flex;
  color: #FF0800;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.buy {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: #68D81E;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.buy:hover {
  background: #82F238;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1290px) {
  .tovari_block {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 30%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .tovari_block {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 85%;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .search {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .tovari_block {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .search {
    width: 90%;
  }

  footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidebar__icon {
    display: block;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 590px) {
  .tovari_block {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> WayStore </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img class="graficlogo" src="img/logo_2.png"></a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="sidebar">
            <h3> Каталог товаров </h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Телефоны и асскесуары </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Мужская одежда </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Женская одежда </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Детская одежда </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Бытовые приборы </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Уличные площадки </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Компьютерные акссесуары </a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
  <div id="sidebar__icon"><a href="#"> &#9776; </a></div>

        <input type="text" name="search" class="search" placeholder="Поиск по сайту">


        <main>

            <div class="tovari_block"> <!-- Товар блоки -->


                <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>
                                <div id="quantity_true">
                                    <h5> Есть в наличии. </h5>
                                    </div>          
                                <div class="button">
                            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=CllgCHrkVmDmsQtcjCmMSdfnSmKtdCgPkWZshzFSbSpBgWxqVJHWcxNKWJdPBVqVbrnFFKvThLV" target="_blank">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button></a>
                            <p> Код товара: 000000 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>
                                <div id="quantity_false">
                                    <h5> Нет в наличии. </h5>
                                    </div>              
                                <div class="button">
                            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=CllgCHrkVmDmsQtcjCmMSdfnSmKtdCgPkWZshzFSbSpBgWxqVJHWcxNKWJdPBVqVbrnFFKvThLV" target="_blank">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button></a>
                            <p> Код товара: 000000 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>
                                <div id="quantity_true">
                                    <h5> Есть в наличии. </h5>
                                    </div>              
                                <div class="button">
                            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=CllgCHrkVmDmsQtcjCmMSdfnSmKtdCgPkWZshzFSbSpBgWxqVJHWcxNKWJdPBVqVbrnFFKvThLV" target="_blank">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button></a>
                            <p> Код товара: 000000 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>
                                <div id="quantity_false">
                                    <h5> Нет в наличии. </h5>
                                    </div>              
                                <div class="button">
                            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=CllgCHrkVmDmsQtcjCmMSdfnSmKtdCgPkWZshzFSbSpBgWxqVJHWcxNKWJdPBVqVbrnFFKvThLV" target="_blank">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button></a>
                            <p> Код товара: 000000 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div> <!-- Товар блоки -->

        <div class="tovari_block"> <!-- Товар блоки -->


                <div class="tovari_block"> <!-- Товар блоки -->


                <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>
                                <div id="quantity_true">
                                    <h5> Есть в наличии. </h5>
                                    </div>          
                                <div class="button">
                            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=CllgCHrkVmDmsQtcjCmMSdfnSmKtdCgPkWZshzFSbSpBgWxqVJHWcxNKWJdPBVqVbrnFFKvThLV" target="_blank">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button></a>
                            <p> Код товара: 000000 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>
                                <div id="quantity_false">
                                    <h5> Нет в наличии. </h5>
                                    </div>              
                                <div class="button">
                            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=CllgCHrkVmDmsQtcjCmMSdfnSmKtdCgPkWZshzFSbSpBgWxqVJHWcxNKWJdPBVqVbrnFFKvThLV" target="_blank">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button></a>
                            <p> Код товара: 000000 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>
                                <div id="quantity_true">
                                    <h5> Есть в наличии. </h5>
                                    </div>              
                                <div class="button">
                            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=CllgCHrkVmDmsQtcjCmMSdfnSmKtdCgPkWZshzFSbSpBgWxqVJHWcxNKWJdPBVqVbrnFFKvThLV" target="_blank">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button></a>
                            <p> Код товара: 000000 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>
                                <div id="quantity_false">
                                    <h5> Нет в наличии. </h5>
                                    </div>              
                                <div class="button">
                            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=CllgCHrkVmDmsQtcjCmMSdfnSmKtdCgPkWZshzFSbSpBgWxqVJHWcxNKWJdPBVqVbrnFFKvThLV" target="_blank">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button></a>
                            <p> Код товара: 000000 </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div> <!-- Товар блоки -->

        </main>

        <footer>
            <div class="social">
                <p> Мы в социальных сетях! </p>
                    <div class="footer_social_img">
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_instagram.png"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_facebook.png"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_twitter.png"></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>

var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
var button = document.getElementById('sidebar__icon');
button.onclick = function() {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar__active');
}
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' товары будут добавлятся, а так сайдбар уже на второй строчке товаров обрывается(

Comment: @MaximLensky Как именно? position: fixed?

Comment: @MaximLensky Я уже сделал адаптацию, всё нормально, нужно решить только с этим сайдбаром, чтобы на всю высоту его растянуть

Comment: @MaximLensky Что-то я не особо понял суть кода

Comment: @MaximLensky Ну логично что вижу) xD

Comment: @MaximLensky Да спасибо)

Comment: @MaximLensky напиши ответ) пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться flex который если не указывать высоту явно сделает её автоматически равную всем flex потомкам и выглядит это так

```css
header {
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

.bar {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 250px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}

.cart {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="items">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```